# Do parallel streams treat upstream iterators in a thread safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

Today I was using a stream that was performing a `parallel()` operation after a map, however; the underlying source is an iterator which is not thread safe which is similar to the [BufferedReader.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines()) implementation.

I originally thought that trySplit would be called on the created thread, however; I observed that the accesses to the iterator have come from multiple threads.

By example, the following silly iterator implementation is just setup with enough elements to cause splitting and also keeps track of the unique threads that accessed the `hasNext` method.

```
class SillyIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private final ArrayDeque<String> src =
        IntStream.range(1, 10000)
            .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
            .collect(toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));
    private Map<String, String> ts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public Set<String> threads() { return ts.keySet(); }
    private String nextRecord = null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        var n = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        ts.put(n, n);
        if (nextRecord != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            nextRecord = src.poll();
            return nextRecord != null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (nextRecord != null || hasNext()) {
            var rec = nextRecord;
            nextRecord = null;
            return rec;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

}
```

Using this to create a stream as follows:

```
var iter = new SillyIterator();
StreamSupport
    .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        iter, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL
    ), false)
    .map(n -> "value = " + n)
    .parallel()
    .collect(toList());

System.out.println(iter.threads());
```

This on my system output the two fork join threads as well as the main thread, which kind of scared me.

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, main]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread safety does not necessarily imply being accessed by only one thread. The important aspect is that there is no concurrent access, i.e. no access by more than one thread at the same time. If the access by different threads is temporally ordered and this ordering also ensures the necessary memory visibility, which is the responsibility of the caller, it still is a thread safe usage.

[The `Spliterator` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html) says:

> Despite their obvious utility in parallel algorithms, spliterators are not expected to be thread-safe; instead, implementations of parallel algorithms using spliterators should ensure that the spliterator is only used by one thread at a time. This is generally easy to attain via *serial thread-confinement*, which often is a natural consequence of typical parallel algorithms that work by recursive decomposition.

The spliterator doesn’t need to be confined to the same thread throughout its lifetime, but there should be a clear handover at the caller’s side ensuring that the old thread stops using it before the new thread starts using it.

But the important takeaway is, the spliterator doesn’t need to be thread safe, hence, the iterator wrapped by a spliterator also doesn’t need to be thread safe.

Note that a typical behavior is splitting and handing over before starting traversal, but since an ordinary `Iterator` doesn’t support splitting, the wrapping spliterator has to iterate and buffer elements to implement splitting. Therefore, the `Iterator` experiences traversal by different threads (but one at a time) when the traversal has not been started from the `Stream` implementation’s perspective.

---

That said, the `lines()` implementation of `BufferedReader` is a bad example which you should not follow. Since it’s centered around a single `readLine()` call, it would be natural to implement `Spliterator` directly instead of implementing a more complicated `Iterator` and have it wrapped via `spliteratorUnknownSize(…)`.

Since your example is likewise centered around a single `poll()` call, it’s also straight-forward to implement `Spliterator` directly:

```java
class SillySpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String> {
    private final ArrayDeque<String> src = IntStream.range(1, 10000)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(toCollection(ArrayDeque::new));

    SillySpliterator() {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, ORDERED | NONNULL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
        String nextRecord = src.poll();
        if(nextRecord == null) return false;
        action.accept(nextRecord);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Depending on your real life case, you may also pass the actual deque size to the constructor and provide the `SIZED` characteristic.

Then, you may use it like

```java
var result = StreamSupport.stream(new SillySpliterator(), true)
    .map(n -> "value = " + n)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you. I don't often need to implement spliterator and actually look for examples in the JDK. Example on the deque is for demonstration, impl in question is related to hadoop. Thanks again for this answer.

Comment: I assumed that it was just an example. That’s why I suggested adding the sized characteristic “depending on your real life case” instead of just adding it to my example. I also tried to emphasize the general pattern behind implementing spliterator directly. Whenever you have some sort of “*get next element or tell me there are no more*” operation like `readLine()`, `poll()`, `fetchNext()`, etc., a `Spliterator` is much simpler to implement. Even using two-method APIs is not harder with a `Spliterator` compared to an `Iterator`. It’s just a matter of getting familiar with it.